# Want to close the sidepanel using the minus icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently the sidepanel opens using PLUS symbol and is closed using the close btn on the sidepanel.
PLUS symbol now changes to minus but it doesn't go back to plus when the sidepanel is closed and also I want to be able to click the minus symbol and close the sidepanel as well.

Hope I made my point clear.
Here is the jsfiddle related to it:
https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/h9yfbden/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn"></i>
</div>
<div class="cd-panel-nvv from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container">
        Content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.glyphicon-plus-sign, .glyphicon-minus-sign{
  top: 30%;
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 1; 
    color: rgb(255, 133, 102);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.glyphicon-plus-sign:hover, .glyphicon-minus-sign:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}

a {
  color: #89ba2c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cd-main-content {
  text-align: center;
}
.cd-main-content .cd-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #89ba2c;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cd-main-content .cd-btn-val {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #89ba2c;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn-val:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cd-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  z-index: 9;
}
.cd-panel::after {
  /* overlay layer */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.cd-panel-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 27px;
  width: 3%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: top 1.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: top 1.3s 0s;
  transition: top 1.3s 0s;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header, .from-left .cd-panel-header {
  top: -50px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header {
  right: 20px;
}
.from-left .cd-panel-header {
  left: 0;
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-header {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
  transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1471px) {
  .cd-panel-header {
    height: 30px;
  }
}

.cd-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cd-panel-close::before, .cd-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before, .no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #901818;
  border-left: 1px solid #c8cacc;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1.8s;
  transition-duration: 1.8s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1271px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1471px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
});

jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not that far...

I only changed `addClass` for `toggleClass`
in `$('.cd-btn').on('click'...`.

And added `$('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");`
to `$('.cd-panel').on('click'...`.

```
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
});

//NVV
jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Updated [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/cpagL7qz/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toggleClass();` and listening to both `$('.cd-btn, .cd-panel')`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/h9yfbden/3/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  //open the lateral panel
  $('.cd-btn, .cd-panel').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
  });
});
```